# next js app directory github action CI/CD path

Tags: github, next.js, github-actions

I'm currently trying to deploy from the app directory to Github Action CI/CD.
But I keep getting a `PageNotFoundError: Cannot find module for page: /` error, and I think the phenomenon that I can't read the app path in my structure is happening. Below is the next.config.js file. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

#### next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

#### nextjs.yml

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```yaml
name: git push into another repo to deploy to vercel

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: pandoc/latex
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install mustache (to update the date)
        run: apk add ruby && gem install mustache
      - name: creates output
        run: sh ./build.sh
      - name: Pushes to another repository
        id: push_directory
        uses: cpina/github-action-push-to-another-repository@main
        env:
          API_TOKEN_GITHUB: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN_GITHUB }}
        with:
          source-directory: 'output'
          destination-github-username: [Seung-hwan285]
          destination-repository-name: [Team-PODO-ODEEGO-FE
]
          user-email: ${{ secrets.OFFICIAL_ACCOUNT_EMAIL }}
          commit-message: ${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}
          target-branch: main
      - name: Test get variable exported by push-to-another-repository
        run: echo $DESTINATION_CLONED_DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature now is supported in Next 13.3

For more information, checkout: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `next export` does not support the experimental `appDir` setting.

For more information, checkout: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap